# Databricks NameError: name 'expr' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When attempting to execute the following spark code in Databricks I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'expr' is not defined


%python
df = sql("select * from xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx")
transfromWithCol = (df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case when first_name = 'Peter' then 1 else 0 end")))
```

Any thoughts

Comment: Can you try the query with triple quotes? Is it giving out same error with changes?

Comment: Hi @Lawhatre, thanks for reaching out. I'm getting the same error with triple quotes

Comment: You have to import `expr` first: `from pyspark.sql.functions import expr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to import "expr" first from the library.  Following is the import statement to avert the encountered error:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
```

Answer (score 1):

- I have received the same error when I have tried a similar code. The following is the error that I have received.

```
data = [[1,'Ana'],[2,'Topson'],[3,'Ceb']]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=['id','gname'])
df.show()

df1 = df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case  when gname =  'Ana'  then  1  else  0  end"))
df1.show()
```

[image]

- You have to install the function from `pyspark.sql.functions` in order to for this to work. Using the following modified code has worked without any issue:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df1 = df.withColumn("MyTestName", expr("case  when gname =  'Ana'  then  1  else  0  end"))
df1.show()
```

[image]